# Apply multiple functions to a pandas groupby apply that returns multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Current I am doing it in three groupby's with each apply returning a dataframe:

```
 fd1 = df.groupby('loan_id').apply(build_feature_set_1)
 fd2 = df.groupby('loan_id').apply(build_feature_set_2)
 fd3 = df.groupby('loan_id').apply(build_feature_set_3)
```

These functions require access to multiple columns so I can't use `agg`.
Essentially I want to be able to do it in a single scan of data i.e a single groupby. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:-

```
fn_list = [build_feature_set_1, build_feature_set_2, build_feature_set_3]

grouped_df = df.groupby('loan_id')

df1, df2, df3 = list(map(lambda x: grouped_df.apply(x), fn_list))
```

Comment: the point is to not use groupby and apply three times. its not very efficient

Comment: You can move group_by out of function but I don't think so that you can apply three different functions to a dataframe in a single go. Edited my answer for a single group_by.